# render json data and partial view with single ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Code given below sends an ajax request to the controller.

```
 if (btid === '01') {
                var allData = {
                    "sessionName": $('#sessionname').val(),
                    "foundStudent": $('#studentId').val(),
                    "code":btid
                }
                var mySession = JSON.stringify(allData);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("RenderView", "ManualFeesCollection")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: mySession,
                    success: function (data) {
                          $('#maindiv').html('')
                          $('#maindiv').html(data)
                          $.each(data.myMonths, function (index, item) {
                           //Here I want to access myMonths as Json
                        })
                    },
                })
```

Below in the Controller Action.

```
public ActionResult RenderView(int code,long foundStudent,int sessionName)
        {
            var months = //get some months
            var myMonths= (from w in months
                        select new
                        {
                            w.Month
                        });// Want access this data in ajax success function
            return PartialView("MonthwiseFees",myMonths);

    }
```

But the problem is I am getting the view in the #maindiv,but not not getting

> myMonths

as json, in the success function of ajax. I need to do something in view with those myMonths.Currently I am sending two ajax request(in the success of another) to accomplish.But I wish I could do it with a single ajax request.Thanks for spending time on my Issue.

- Update1: code of partial view

  ```
  {

  <tr>
      <td>
       @x
      </td>
      <td>
        @months[no]
      </td>
      <td>
          @Html.CheckBox(" " + @x, new { @class="check",id="check"})
          @Html.Label(" ", new { @class="lbl"})
       </td>
  </tr>
  x = x + 1;
  ```

  }

  ```
               <input type="button" class="mybutton btn btn-small btn-primary" value="Show >"/>

          </div>
      <div class="span7" id="classwiseheads">
          </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with the months in a view? Why dont you do it in a partialview.cshtml itself by passing a model

Comment: This partial view is not strogly typed.So, I need to use javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks goes to  [Murali Murugesan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559213/murali-murugesan) and [yasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182982/yasser) for help

I used the concept of [Murali Murugesan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559213/murali-murugesan) by sending necessary data the in ViewBag.But since my partial view is  `Not Strongly Typed` ,for this reason I needed to use javascript.

I edited my controller Action like below

```
var months = fcDetailsService.GetStudentWiseCollectionDetail(foundStudent, sessionName, "01");
            var data = (from w in months
                        select new
                        {
                            w.Month

                        });
            ViewBag.Months = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            if (data != null)
            {
                return PartialView("MonthwiseFees", data);
            }
            else
                return Json("MonthwiseFees");
```

Then in my javascript, I did below

```
$(function () {
        var i = 0;
        var myarray = new Array();
        myarray =@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Months)
            $('.check').each(function () {
                for (var x = 0; x < myarray.length; x++)
                {
                        var me = (JSON.stringify(myarray[x].Month))
                        if ($.trim(this.name) === $.trim(me)) {
                            $(this).prop("checked", true)
                            $(this).attr("disabled", true)
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send `text/html` and `application/json` for a single request. You could send either one.

If you are returning PartialView from controller, then the content type will be set to `text/html`. But still you can render the JSON as part of partial view.

```
public ActionResult RenderView(int code,long foundStudent,int sessionName)
{
    var months = //get some months
    var myMonths= (from w in months
                select new
                {
                    w.Month
                });
        ViewBag.Months=myMonths;
    return PartialView("MonthwiseFees");

}
```

Then  in your partial view

```
<script>
var myJSArray=@Html.Raw(JSON.Encode(ViewBag.Months)
</script>
```

jQuery

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#maindiv').html('')
    $('#maindiv').html(data)
    $.each(myJSArray, function(index, item) {
        //myJSArray will be available in window scope now
    })
}
```

**Update:** Based on updated question

Controller

```
public ActionResult RenderView(int code,long foundStudent,int sessionName)
{
    var months = //get some months
    var myMonths= (from w in months
                select new
                {
                    w.Month
                });        
    return PartialView("MonthwiseFees",myMonths);

}
```

This will check all the check boxes as I pass `true` for Html.CheckBox. This needs to be determined with the model and months array

```
@model List<string>

@using System.Globalization;

@{

    Layout = null;
    string[] months =DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames;
    var countMonths=months.Count();
    int x = 1;
}
<div>

@for (int no=0;no<countMonths-1;no++)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
         @x
        </td>
        <td>
          @months[no]
        </td>
        <td>
            //determine true/false by comparing months and Model
            @Html.CheckBox(" " + @x, model.Contains(months[x]), new { @class="check",id="check"})           
         </td>
    </tr>
    x = x + 1;
}
</div>
```

***jQuery***

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#maindiv').html('');
    $('#maindiv').html(data);        
}
```

Comment: having problem in var myJSArray=@Html.Raw(JSON.Encode(ViewBag.Months) How can I use it in the success function of ajax

Comment: @janina, what are you trying to do with `months` in success callback

Comment: there are some 12 check boxes, from 1 to 12... if(arrayOfMonth=[1,2,3])  then January,Feb,March gets checkede,and this partial view is not strongly typed

Comment: @janina, all those 12 check boxes are in the partial view? or in main view?

Comment: all of them are in the partial view

Comment: @janina, Nice. Could you please add your partial view code? You can do that in partial view and send the content to ajax. No need of sending additional json data :)

Comment: I don't understand what u said, but I updated my code

Comment: @janina, I updated my answer. Please try it and let me know. Thanks for Jon Skeet as well for a quick answer in a comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7867381/1559213)

Comment: Thanks and + for suggesting veiwbag

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with your following code

```
var myMonths= (from w in months
                        select new
                        {
                            w.Month
                        });
```

Here I am assuming your myMonths gets filled with a list of integers. I suggest adding a `.ToList();` to the above code. So now it becomes :

```
var myMonths= (from w in months
                        select new
                        {
                            w.Month
                        }).ToList();
```

Now let's check your jquery code, your ajax's success method look like this

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#maindiv').html('')
    $('#maindiv').html(data)
    $.each(data.myMonths, function(index, item) {
        //Here I want to access myMonths as Json
    })
}
```

Here you write `$('#maindiv').html(data)`, data here is a collection of integers (collection of months), .html() wont work that way.

Now since you are using this ajax call to get the JSON values only. I don't see the need to return a Partial View for that. Your return statement from your action could look like :

```
return Json(myMonths, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and now when you use the following jquery, you will be able to access each month as required:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    // here is your month in the 'item' variable.
    $('#maindiv').html(item)
})
```

### Update 1:

I see you are trying to load your partial view using an ajax call and then also use the data returned in that ajax call.

Why dont you load your partial view using the `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.Action` ([how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766554/mvc-html-partial-or-html-action)). And ideally that partial view should have a call to your action which return JSON data which then you could use accordingly.

### Update 2:

Your latest comment says

> > One page load I don't need that view.I need that view on some button clicked.

This could be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11964905/1182982

Comment: $('#maindiv').html(data) here maindiv will filled with the partial view, and I am trying to do someting in this partial view using myMonths

Comment: why would you want to fill a partial view with an ajax call ? You could use `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.Action` to load your partial view and then send a ajax call from that view.

Comment: because I don't want any refresh.. There are already some necessary data in the existing view

Comment: have updated the answer. Please have a look and revert incase this doesnt work for you.

Comment: No, it wont cause a refresh. The partial view will be loaded on page load itself.

Comment: One page load I don't need that view.I need that view on some button clicked.

Comment: This you should mention in your question my friend :P Please update your question accordingly.