# asp.net MVC layout.cshtml's js files get loaded and called multiple times

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new MVC and have a page layout that looks like the below image. The problem is all module level header,sidemenu,footer related js files are bundled together and these header menu,side menu,footer are in _Layout.cshtml page. The JS files of all these sections gets loaded and executed everytime I go from home(Index.cshtml) view to Playlist menu item(Playlist.cshtml) view. The problem is if I play a song in footer in Home page,and then go to Playlist Page(Both Index.cshtml and Playlist.cshtml are rendered in body section), then I need the same song to be playing in PlayList.cshtml page, not reload JS file to create a new music player in every new page. How do I achieve this? Play the same music in footer,no matter whih page(View) I am in unless I change the music myself.

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGUTf.jpg)

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>@Page.Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <!-- Favicon icon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="~/assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <!-- Google font-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Required Fremwork -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Template/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="~/Content/css/ChatStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Style.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/css/main.css">

        <!-- Responsive.css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/css/responsive.css">

        <!--color css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/css/color/color-1.min.css" id="color" />
        @RenderSection("head", required: false)
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Album/css/albums.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Scripts/MediaElementJS/js/mediaelement-and-player_2.13.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Scripts/MediaElementJS/mep-feature-playlist-master/mep-feature-playlist.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Poppins.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        <style>
            .sticky-footer {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            /*original*/
            .liked::before {
                color: #600;
                content: '\f004';
            }

            .not-liked::before {
                color: #aaa;
                content: '\f08a';
            }

            .smallWidth {
                width: 400px;
            }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body class="sidebar-mini fixed">
        <div class="loader-bg">
            <div class="loader-bar">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
               <!-- Navbar-->
            <header class="main-header-top hidden-print">
                <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img class="img-fluid able-logo" src="~/assets/images/logo.png" alt="Theme-logo"></a>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                    <!-- Sidebar toggle button--><a href="#!" data-toggle="offcanvas" class="sidebar-toggle"></a>
                    <!-- Navbar Right Menu-->
                    <div class="navbar-custom-menu f-right p-absolute">
                        <ul class="top-nav">
                            <!--Notification Menu-->

                            <li class="dropdown pc-rheader-submenu message-notification search-toggle">
                                <a href="#!" id="morphsearch-search" class="drop icon-circle txt-white">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-search-alt-1"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown notification-menu">
                                <a href="#!" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                    <i class="icon-bell"></i>
                                    <span class="badge badge-danger header-badge">9</span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="not-head">You have <b class="text-primary">4</b> new notifications.</li>
                                    <li class="bell-notification">
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="media">
                                            <span class="media-left media-icon">
                                                <img class="img-circle" src="~/assets/images/avatar-1.png" alt="User Image">
                                            </span>
                                            <div class="media-body"><span class="block">Lisa sent you a mail</span><span class="text-muted block-time">2min ago</span></div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="bell-notification">
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="media">
                                            <span class="media-left media-icon">
                                                <img class="img-circle" src="~/assets/images/avatar-2.png" alt="User Image">
                                            </span>
                                            <div class="media-body"><span class="block">Server Not Working</span><span class="text-muted block-time">20min ago</span></div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="bell-notification">
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="media">
                                            <span class="media-left media-icon">
                                                <img class="img-circle" src="~/assets/images/avatar-3.png" alt="User Image">
                                            </span>
                                            <div class="media-body"><span class="block">Transaction xyz complete</span><span class="text-muted block-time">3 hours ago</span></div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="not-footer">
                                        <a href="#!">See all notifications.</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- chat dropdown -->
                            <li class="pc-rheader-submenu ">
                                <a href="#!" class="drop icon-circle displayChatbox">
                                    <i class="icon-bubbles"></i>
                                    <span id="msgCount" class="badge badge-danger header-badge blink"></span>
                                </a>

                            </li>
                            <!-- window screen -->
                            <li class="pc-rheader-submenu">
                                <a href="#!" class="drop icon-circle" onclick="javascript:toggleFullScreen()">
                                    <i class="icon-size-fullscreen"></i>
                                </a>

                            </li>
                            <!-- User Menu-->
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#!" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle drop icon-circle drop-image">
                                    <span><img class="img-circle " src="~/assets/images/avatar-1.png" style="width:40px;" alt="User Image"></span>
                                    <span>John <b>Doe</b> <i class=" icofont icofont-simple-down"></i></span>

                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu settings-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#!"><i class="icon-settings"></i> Settings</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="profile.html"><i class="icon-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="message.html"><i class="icon-envelope-open"></i> My Messages</a></li>
                                    <li class="p-0">
                                        <div class="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="lock-screen.html"><i class="icon-lock"></i> Lock Screen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#!"><i class="icon-logout"></i> Logout</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <!-- search -->
                        <div id="morphsearch" class="morphsearch">
                            <form class="morphsearch-form">

                                <input class="morphsearch-input" type="search" placeholder="Search..." />

                                <button class="morphsearch-submit" type="submit">Search</button>

                            </form>
                            <div class="morphsearch-content">
                                <div class="dummy-column">
                                    <h2>People</h2>
                                    <a class="dummy-media-object" href="#!">
                                        <img class="round" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/81b58502541f9445253f30497e53c280?s=50&d=identicon&r=G" alt="Sara Soueidan" />
                                        <h3>Sara Soueidan</h3>
                                    </a>

                                    <a class="dummy-media-object" href="#!">
                                        <img class="round" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/9bc7250110c667cd35c0826059b81b75?s=50&d=identicon&r=G" alt="Shaun Dona" />
                                        <h3>Shaun Dona</h3>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dummy-column">
                                    <h2>Popular</h2>
                                    <a class="dummy-media-object" href="#!">
                                        <img src="~/assets/images/avatar-1.png" alt="PagePreloadingEffect" />
                                        <h3>Page Preloading Effect</h3>
                                    </a>

                                    <a class="dummy-media-object" href="#!">
                                        <img src="~/assets/images/avatar-1.png" alt="DraggableDualViewSlideshow" />
                                        <h3>Draggable Dual-View Slideshow</h3>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dummy-column">
                                    <h2>Recent</h2>
                                    <a class="dummy-media-object" href="#!">
                                        <img src="~/assets/images/avatar-1.png" alt="TooltipStylesInspiration" />
                                        <h3>Tooltip Styles Inspiration</h3>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="dummy-media-object" href="#!">
                                        <img src="~/assets/images/avatar-1.png" alt="NotificationStyles" />
                                        <h3>Notification Styles Inspiration</h3>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /morphsearch-content -->
                            <span class="morphsearch-close"><i class="icofont icofont-search-alt-1"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- search end -->
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <!-- Side-Nav-->
            <aside class="main-sidebar hidden-print ">
                <section class="sidebar" id="sidebar-scroll">

                    <div class="user-panel">
                        <div class="f-left image"><img src="~/assets/images/avatar-1.png" alt="User Image" class="img-circle"></div>
                        <div class="f-left info">
                            <p>John Doe</p>
                            <p class="designation">Weather <i class="icofont icofont-caret-down m-l-5"></i></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- sidebar profile Menu-->
                    <ul class="nav sidebar-menu extra-profile-list">
                        <li>
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="profile.html">
                                <i class="icon-user"></i>
                                <span class="menu-text">View Profile</span>
                                <span class="selected"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <i class="icon-settings"></i>
                                <span class="menu-text">Settings</span>
                                <span class="selected"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <i class="icon-logout"></i>
                                <span class="menu-text">Logout</span>
                                <span class="selected"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Sidebar Menu-->
                    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                        <li class="nav-level">Navigation</li>
                        <li class="active treeview">
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="index.html">
                                <i class="icon-speedometer"></i><span> Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-level">Components</li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i><span> UI Elements</span><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="accordion.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Accordion</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="button.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Button</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="label-badge.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Label Badge</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="bootstrap-ui.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Grid system</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="box-shadow.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Box Shadow</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="color.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Color</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="light-box.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Light Box</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="notification.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Notification</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="panels-wells.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Panels-Wells</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="tabs.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Tabs</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="tooltips.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Tooltips</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="typography.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Typography</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!"><i class="icon-chart"></i><span> Charts &amp; Maps</span><span class="label label-success menu-caption">New</span><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="float-chart.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Float Charts</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="morris-chart.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Morris Charts</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!"><i class="icon-book-open"></i><span> Forms</span><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="form-elements-bootstrap.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Form Elements Bootstrap</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="form-elements-materialize.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Form Elements Material</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="form-elements-advance.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Form Elements Advance</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="treeview">

                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" id="mnItemPlaylist">
                                <i class="icon-list"></i><span> Play Lists</span>

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-level">More</li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!"><i class="icon-docs"></i><span>Pages</span><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li class="treeview">
                                    <a href="#!"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i><span> Authentication</span><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="register1.html" target="_blank"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Register 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="login1.html" target="_blank"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i><span> Login 1</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="forgot-password.html" target="_blank"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i><span> Forgot Password</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="profile.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Profile</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="lock-screen.html" target="_blank"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Lock Screen</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="404.html" target="_blank"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Error 404</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="sample-page.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Sample Page</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="search-result.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Search Result</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-level">Menu Level</li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!"><i class="icofont icofont-company"></i><span>Menu Level 1</span><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!">
                                        <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
                                        Level Two
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="treeview">
                                    <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!">
                                        <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
                                        <span>Level Two</span>
                                        <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!">
                                                <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
                                                Level Three
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!">
                                                <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
                                                <span>Level Three</span>
                                                <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!">
                                                        <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
                                                        Level Four
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="#!">
                                                        <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
                                                        Level Four
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </aside>
            <!-- Sidebar chat start -->
              <!-- Sidebar chat end-->

            <div class="content-wrapper">

                <!-- Container-fluid starts -->
                <!-- Main content starts -->
                <div class="container-fluid">

                        <!-- Item -->
                        @RenderBody()

                </div>
                <!-- Main content ends -->
                <!-- Container-fluid ends -->

                <!-- Page Footer-->
                <footer id="sticky-footer" class="sticky-footer">

                    @Html.Partial("_fullPlayer")
                </footer>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="~/assets/plugins/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/assets/plugins/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Required Fremwork -->

        @*Added by*@
        <script src="~/Content/Template/vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Content/Template/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20160511/json2.js"></script>

        <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Modules/Home/ChatBarJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- notification -->
        <script src="~/assets/plugins/notification/js/bootstrap-growl.min.js"></script>
        <div id="modPlayList" class="modcon" style="width: 20%;height:20%"></div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mediaelement")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modules")
        @RenderSection("scripts", false)
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () { // JQuery not loaded here, $ is undefined
                $.getScript('../Scripts/Modules/musicCloud.js', function () {

                    var $window = $(window);
                    var nav = $('.fixed-button');
                    $window.scroll(function () {
                        if ($window.scrollTop() >= 200) {
                            nav.addClass('active');
                        }
                        else {
                            nav.removeClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                    $(function () {
                        $('#mnItemPlaylist').click(function () {

                            $.get('@Url.Action("PlayList", "PlayList",new {url = "/api/albums" })', function (data) {
                                debugger;
                                musicCloud.playlist.AppendToAlbums(data, 'New Releases');
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
           });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: are you really saying you don't want the page to refresh when moving between views, so that the music player doesn't restart (because the whole page has been reloaded? If so, then consider using ajax and partial views, or use a client-side MVC framework such as Angular

Comment: @adyson i am already using ajax but how can i render a partial view with json data manipulated through jquery(after successful ajax call) and replace the @renderbody() in _layout.cshtml which already uses index.cshtml with the partialview say _Playlist.cshtml

Comment: "a partial view with json data"...what do you mean by this? Partial views are supposed to contain HTML, not JSON. Anyway, you don't want to replace the renderbody() Razor method, this runs server-side. What you need is that index.cshtml doesn't really display anything by itself, what it does is contains some JS code which loads the relevant partial view based on some data e.g. menu selection. Possibly you don't even want a layout page at all, just put everything in the index view, which becomes the only full view in your application

Comment: I'm really sorry for confusing you.This is my first project using Asp.net MVC,self taught. In the layout image i attached above in my earlier comment, The section that renders body @RenderBody has Index.cshtml rendered(with all the music players). Everything else footer and menus are in layout page.  My only requirement is that whenever i click on menu item, I want to load a page on the RenderBody() section refreshing only that section like how we do it in webforms with masterpage ScriptManager  and update panel.The other page which i want to load has dynamic html bound with json data

Comment: "I want to load a page on the RenderBody() section refreshing only that section"...yes, that's what you'd use ajax and partial views for, in an MVC setting. It will be a lot easier if you have everything in index.cshtml though, with no layout page, then your menu items can easily trigger the ajax request (instead of triggering a link to a new view). The concept is basically called a "Single Page Application"

Comment: I achieved what I wanted to do using partial views and viewdata. After reading so many articles, I came across two ways of doing it.

Comment: I achieved what I wanted to do using partial views and viewdata, that is click on menu item in _layout and load a partial view with data in single ajax request in the RenderBody section of layout page. After reading so many articles, I came across two ways of doing it. 1)Passing the entire PartialView with data as JSON 2)Using Viewbag/ViewData to pass the data and return partial view in single ajax call. So, no 2 was the best option for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811732/render-json-data-and-partial-view-with-single-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I wanted to do using partial views and viewdata, that is click on menu item in _layout and load a partial view with data in single ajax request in the RenderBody section of layout page. After reading so many articles, I came across two ways of doing it. 1)Passing the entire PartialView with data as JSON 2)Using Viewbag/ViewData to pass the data and return partial view in single ajax call. So, no 2 was the best option for me [render json data and partial view with single ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811732/render-json-data-and-partial-view-with-single-ajax-request)